# Android OpenGL e-books?

Tags: android, opengl-es

Are there any e-books out there on the topic of OpenGL in Android?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't said how experienced you are with OpenGL and/or Android in general, but I'll assume that you are familiar with the basics.

In that case, the two books in this series both have significant coverage of OpenGL, which you can see by looking inside at their table of contents:

- [Pro Android Games](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226471)
- [Pro Android 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430226595)

Those, together with a [reference book on standard OpenGL ES 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321502795) should be all you need for a long, long time.

Comment: i am beginner, so any beginners guide?

Comment: @Jitesh A beginner to what, Android or OpenGL? Or both?