# How to enable and disable openGL2.0 in android

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want to learn OpenGL2.0 in android.But I didn't find the way how to enable and disable OpenGL2.0 in andorid and Android Browser. If anyone knows please help me on this..

Comment: What exactly do you mean under : "disable opengl" ?

Comment: To learn OpenGL ES on android refer this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446592/android-opengl-e-books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you enable or disable OpenGL 2.0, or 1.1, or any other version.  Rather, either your device supports it or it doesn't.  If you want to find out how to check what it supports, we can help you with that.

To use the 2.0 functionality simply cast your GL10 object to a GL20 object and start calling the GL20 specific methods.

Comment: Thanx for reply.Yah, I am looking to that point only.How to check what it supports?

Comment: @jettimadhuChowdary, You can use gl.glGetString(GL10.GL_VERSION).  See this thread- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314115/android-opengl-es-vbo-support-or-not